# What is the purpose of Origin Points?

Tags: origin

As of May 28, 2013, Origin has introduced "Origin Points", which purportedly helps track your achievements in some of EA's games on PC.

From [EA's help center](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/origin/origin/origin-faq):

> Origin Points help you track your achievements and measure your progress while playing some of our games [...].

You get these points naturally while playing your game and getting achievements, but is there any point to these points? Can you spend them on things, or are they just for pride and banter?

Comment: If you want a guess, I'd say it's EA's attempt to get achievement-obsessed people to spend more money on more Origin games to get more Origin Points so that they can wave their big Origin Points score around and think it makes them superior. You know, pretty much like XBL and Microsoft Gamer Points or whatever they decided to call them.

Comment: Awww bless you EA. Still trying to compete with Steam.

Comment: Must....not....downvote....due to hatred.....of....origin

Comment: Origin, a.k.a *wannabe gaming community*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only real answer seems to be, that nobody actually knows. I have accumulated points that I have no idea what to do with. I have trolled forums etc to find out, but to no avail. Seems we will have to wait for Origin to tell us what they are for, and how to spend\use them. In the meanwhile, continue to stack them up.

Answer (score 3):

They are just like your [Gamerscore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live#Gamerscore) on the [Xbox 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360) and [Xbox One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_One) when using [Xbox Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live).

Answer (score 1):

Since EA has introduced the *Origin Points* in the beta there has been no word on what Origin Points are for. I distinctly remember reading that EA has "big plans for achievements and Origin Points" but as of yet it hasn't released any information at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a useless form of measuring your progress in the game. You can't use them to buy anything like DLCs and games.

Answer (score -2):

You can now use Origin points to buy DLC - at least for mass effect 3.

Comment: This is incorrect. Mass Effect 3 DLC may be purchased with _BioWare Points_, which are something different.

Answer (score -3):

From https://help.ea.com/article/achievements-and-origin-points:

> PC gamers who installed Battlefield 3, Mass Effect 3, and Dead Space 3 via Origin can view their Origin Point total and the in-game achievements they’ve earned by clicking on the achievements icon in Origin In Game (Shift+F1 while in the game), by viewing their “mini profile” (where your username and avatar are displayed), by viewing the achievements module on the game detail page, or by viewing your profile. (Please note: only gamers playing Battlefield 3, Mass effect 3, and Dead Space 3 will see their Origin Points or be able to view the achievements module).

Honestly I think the points are just a means of provocation. It doesn't really mean much.

Comment: Isn't that "answer" just c&p of what is already quoted in the question?